# PHP Mailer Multiple recipients

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using php mailer for mail triggering.
Its working fine. But I gave 2 to 5 recipients, it sends the mail to only one recipient. In future, I have to trigger a mail to nearly 100 recipients.. 
I've shared my code below.. Please check it..

```
 require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; 

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'karthick****@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('karth*******@gmail.com', 'A**n');

    $addresses = explode(',',$emailM);
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        $mail->AddAddress($address);
    }


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = 'Need for '.$keyword.'';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi,The Message';


if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Qoute has been sent to all the Manufacturers';
    echo "$address";

}
```

Comment: Are the email addresses in `$addresses` valid? You should at least add debug message in each foreach-loop cycle.

Comment: Are you sure it's only sending to one? You're echoing `$address` at the end, which will only ever contain the last address you added, but the message will still be sent to all of them (though you should check the return value of `addAddress()` to be sure it's working).

Comment: I don't think you're going about this in the right way - given the "all the Manufacturers" text at the end, I doubt very much you really want to be adding them all to the same message (where they will all see each other's addresses). You should send a separate message to each one. See [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for how to do that efficiently.

Comment: What does `$addresses` / `$emailM` look like?

Comment: $emailM shows    email1@gmail.comemail2@gmail.comemail3@gmail.com....   $address shows email1@gmail.com..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code looks like it should be doing the trick. Make sure that `$address` doesn't contain any whitespace for the entries. For safe measure, add the `trim()`
function.

```
$mail->AddAddress(trim($address));
```

If that does not work, make sure that you're recipient addresses are real.

Additionally, in case the privacy of the recipients is of concern, I would recommend you use **`AddBCC()`** instead of **`AddAddress()`** so that their addresses are not revealed.

Answer (score 0):

A basic idea is that make different connection (object) for each your mailing address like below **if You don't have so much addresses in your array.**

```
 require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; 

$addresses = explode(',',$emailM);
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'karthick****@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('karth*******@gmail.com', 'A**n');


        $mail->AddAddress($address);


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = 'Need for '.$keyword.'';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi,The Message';


if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Qoute has been sent to all the Manufacturers';
    echo "$address";

 }
```

**UPDATE :**

The second idea is that you can remove recepients each time and add new one and then send like  below

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; 

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'karthick****@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('karth*******@gmail.com', 'A**n');

    $addresses = explode(',',$emailM);
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {

        // for clear last recipients

        $mail->ClearAllRecipients( ) 


        $mail->AddAddress($address);


        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  

           $mail->Subject = 'Need for '.$keyword.'';
           $mail->Body    = 'Hi,The Message';


        if(!$mail->send()) {
          echo 'Message could not be sent.';
          echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       } else {
           echo 'Qoute has been sent to all the Manufacturers';
          echo "$address";

       }

 }
```

Comment: Don't do that. It will work, but it's slow, wasteful and inefficient.

Comment: No, not true. PHP Mailer can support multiple Recipients at the same time.

Comment: i knew it. but when you are continously adding addresses and then send it will shows all receipient in each of receipients

Comment: Even with that edit, you're still adding overhead simply because you have some aversion to calling `clearAddresses()`.

Comment: ...and your second edit is nearly the same as the original post, but makes the same mistake as marmalade's answer :)

Comment: see once again i have updated it. that was saved by mistake

Comment: @ArunKarthick check once again.

Comment: @Synchro use my second update and try. i think you will get your answer.

Comment: That's better, though there's more you could move outside the loop, but I think the OP was asking the wrong question - see my comment on the question.

Comment: I tried ur code @SatishSharma... But its showing error like this...                                                                                                           Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: @Arun, that suggests that some of your addresses are invalid, and you're not checking the results of `addAddress`, so you end up trying to send messages with no recipient.

Comment: @ArunKarthick your `$addresses`  must have valid no of emails

Comment: This is kinda the recommended way of sending by PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps